# How to margin text from top border in textarea

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to margin text from top border of textarea box?
I have used text indent, but it only makes space between text and left border of the textarea box, which is great, but i also want same space between text and top border of textarea box.
Here is my html:

```
<textarea class="input-text" name="instructions" id="instructions"></textarea>
```

css:

```
.input-text{
    width: 20%;
    height: 44px;
    text-indent: 16px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px lightgray solid;
    resize: none;
    color: lightgray;
}
```

As I am new to this, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Sorry if the question was inappropriate or not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `padding`, and `box-sizing` to stop the padding increasing the actual box size:

```css
.input-text{
    width: 20%;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px lightgray solid;
    resize: none;
    color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="input-text" name="instructions" id="instructions"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great, this is it! Can't aprove right now, need to wait 9 min. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```css
.input-text{
    width: 20%;
    height: 44px;
    text-indent: 16px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px lightgray solid;
    resize: none;
    color: lightgray;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="input-text" name="instructions" id="instructions"></textarea>
```

Try this

```css
textarea {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="5"  placeholder="Your Text here"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-model):

[image: Box Model Diagram]

The `margin` is the space between the border and the next element.

To put space between the border and the text content you need `padding`

```css
.input-text{
    width: 20%;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px lightgray solid;
    resize: none;
    color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="input-text" name="instructions" id="instructions">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</textarea>
```